# NodeJS oAuth2.0 integration or server

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

**TL;DR**
I've build oAuth consumer apps, which login a user so i'm not too worried about the apps logic. we can use passportjs for that. but how do we set up an oAuth server to which apps connect, after which they are cleared to access an endpoint on the API (which is an entire different app)

---

Setup:

- 1 big REST API (written in NodeJS,on the express framwork)
- 2 apps in development talking to the API
- dozens of app idea's in the pipeline using that same API

Authentication requirements:

- apps use oAuth to authenticate a user
- apps have various authorization levels providing it access to certain corners of the API
- users can login if they want to with their google account (most of the users have a company google account and would be required to authenticate with it. certain external users could use their google or auth manually)

I've currently setup several proof of concepts, with different modules and authentication systems, like [oauth2orize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize) and oauth via social platforms with [passportjs](http://passportjs.org/)

But at this moment i'm quite sure of:

- we want oauth, and need to setup our own oauth server to which all apps can authenticate
- apps can still use passportJS to connect with the self made oAuth server

What is still unclear to me

- how can we let a user login to an app with his google account, providing him access to certain parts of the REST API.